# Binding to items in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, bind

I have problem with binding. My XAML structure in WPF looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding cacheList}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding type}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding loadFromCache}" CommandParameter="-- BIND TO CLICKED ITEM --"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ItemsControl>
```

And to this moment everything works fine. When I click on items in ItemsControl I notice this in ModelView class. But I don't know which particular item was clicked.

I tried bind to "this" object by:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding loadCache}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

But in this case I get strange result, because I receive (check in output): App.ViewModels.MainViewModel, which is context for all view, not this particular item.

How to do it, so I could resolve which item was clicked?

EDIT:
I found a solution: use a ListBox (or anything deriving from Selector control) in order to use the SelectedItem property. But it does not satisfy me, I want stay by ItemsControl.

Comment: You can change `ItemTemplate` to be a `Button` and bind `Command` to `loadCache` (via `RelativeSource`) and `CommandParameter` to current `DataContext`

Comment: Or just put the trigger inside the template (under StackPanel to be more precise).

Comment: Why don't you want to use a ListBox? It was designed to solve exactly your problem, in a way the user is accustomed to (select with keybd etc).

Comment: I don't want use ListBox, because of style and template. My itemsControl is strongly styled. I know I can override ListBox style too, with pretty the same style. I starting doing this, but @James Harcourt answer show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know you want to do this with bindings, you can take this approach.

First, make your text box the clickable area and create an input binding to handle the mouse click:

```
<TextBlock Tag="{Binding}" Text="{Binding Name}">
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
         <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ItemClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

You can see the MouseBinding handles the LeftClick of the mouse and and the specified command binds to an ICommand which is defined in the item object type of your items control:

```
 public class YourObject
 {
     public ICommand ItemClick { get { return new ItemClickCommand(); } }
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Then the command instance "ItemClickCommand" will fire when the LeftClick happens - and you will have the item as the command parameter:

```
public class ItemClickCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // parameter will be the item clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm in MVVM. It's for learning, your answers is good for immediately solution. But I want figure out how to do it by bind.

Comment: Your solution working.I started believing there is no any other way than using anything deriving from Selector control, and bind SelectedItem property.